# Programming language without additional requirements

Tags: windows, programming-languages

Soon I will be coding the file patcher for my application (check if the files are up-to-date and download newest if not) so its not much to code.

The problem is that I don't want the application users to be forced to use additional libraries like `.NET` (even though I like to code in `vb.net` or `C#`). I keep in mind that the `.NET framework` is installing together with the `Windows` but still there are plenty people who somehow doesn't have this framework installed, and thats why I'm looking for the programming language that wont require an additional libraries to run the application.

I haven't got much knowledge about programming in `C++`/`Java` but I have some experience with the `AutoIT, vb.net, C#`.

So the question is, **what programming language will be the best for this purpose**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is for "what language is available on any version of Windows without additional requirements". There are many other options for "what I can use to create application that can be xcopy deployed on any version of Windows".

---

JavaScript is probably your best bet - it is supported on most recent versions of Windows (according to [Wikipedia article - Windows Script Host](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script) JavaScript available for scripting starting with Windows 98). Allows basic operation with files and HTTP communication - maybe enough for simple patching application.

Next would be native Win32 application, but lack of C++ experience will make it hard.

Comment: What about Delphi? What you think?

Comment: @Lucas JavaScript (+VBScript) are the only languages I know that are guaranteed to be present and not require any additional runtimes. I don't know about Delphi - feel free to investigate yourself.

Comment: One will have really hard time trying to do binary I/O using JavaScript via WSH -- such support simply does not exist. So I'm not really sure it's a viable approach to do *patching* (unless something other than binary I/O is meant).

Comment: @kostix - good point on binary IO (command line ftp client can be used to deal with binaries if one really wants to). Rereading the question I probably should have simply voted down/close instead of answering title version ("what language") instead of actual post ("xcopy deploy-able application for all versions of Windows").

Answer (score 2):

[Freepascal](http://www.freepascal.org/), [D](http://dlang.org/) and [Go](http://golang.org) — to name a few — are much easier to program than C++ and could be told to produce statically-compiled binaries (not dependent on anything but certain system DLLs).

I, personally, would use the latter as it has all the necessary tools (including HTTP and binary I/O) in its standard library and is super-easy to get started with.